# SQL system versioning : Is it posible to insert record in HISTORY table at the same time inserting it in Main table

Tags: sql-server, versioning, audit-trail

We have enabled system versioning in our database for required tables. Now we are showing Audit trail to user in UI using HISTORY table. Only problem is that we need to Union HISTORY table with Main table to show Audit with current record.

If there is any provision so that current record also insert in HISTORY table, we doesn't require to do UNION.

Comment: Are you using triggers?

Comment: We are not using triggers. System versioning is  a feature of Sql server.

Comment: If it's really a big deal for you, create a view that abstracts out the `union all`. Then you can just run selects against the view.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server system versioning, you have to use UNION to include current record.
Simplest solution for the user UI will be to create set of views doing UNION of current and history tables.

You can find it documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15):
The current table contains the current value for each row. The history table contains each previous value for each row, if any, and the start time and end time for the period for which it was valid.